# Print the matched string except the last character in lex

Tags: lex

I'm quite confused how to go about the following problem. Suppose I match a string in the form 'xyz!' in lex, but now I want to print only the string 'xyz' which doesn't include the last character of the initial matched string. I do know how to print the matched string,

`printf("String:%s", yytext)`

but not sure how to print only the string 'xyz'. Can someone please clarify this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This actually has little to do with (f)lex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("String:%.*s", yyleng - 1, yytext);
```

`*` in a printf format usually means "get the numeric value from the next argument, which must be an `int`. So if `yyleng` (which is the token length) were 4, then printf would do the equivalent of `printf("String:%.3s", yytext)`, which would mean "Print at most 3 characters from `yytext`.

See [man printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for lots more details.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But if I want to print the last character what would be the command?

Comment: `putchar(yytext[yyleng - 1])` would work. So would `printf("%s", yytext + yyleng - 1);`.